# pass scope function to cloned(and compiled) angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-compile

I have an angular directive, which can take a parent controller function as attribute. During DOM manipulation, this angular directive is cloned, compiled and placed into the beginning part of the DOM. As a result, the passed in parent controller function does not work anymore, since there is no parent controller anymore. How could I solve this? Could I pass the parent controller function from the original to the clone when I'm compiling it? I have tried this, but it is not working:

```
$timeout(function () {
        $scope.test ="passed content";
        var compiledClonedDirective = $compile(clonedDirective)($scope);
        divInTheBeginningPartOfTheDOM.prepend(clonedDirective);});
function getBack() {
   console.log($scope.test);
}
```

This getBack() function is used in the cloned directive. When it is activated, it logs undefined. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution was to copy the parent controller function to rootScope, and then call it from the rootScope in the cloned and replaced directive (directive's controller). But I would like to avoid using rootScope if possible.